# Presto full join with large table(0.9 billion records) much slower than Hive

Tags: hive, presto

I'm doing benchmark performance of Hive vs Presto. Here's the condition and facts:

- full join of a large table(ecu_data) and a small temp table. both table is a hive external table with OSS as storage. the file format is Parquet.
- data size: ecu_data - 0.9 billion records, temp table - ~1million records
- Presto cluster: 3 nodes. memory pools for each node: general pool - 15GB, reserved pool - disabled, Headroom pool - 2GB
- Performance: hive - 148 minutes; Presto - 240 minutes

the CPU/memory utilization level of 3 presto clusters sounds low.(cpu 17% utilized)

The Presto full join of ecu_data/temp table.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "
INSERT INTO ${PST_HIVE_DEST_DB}.${PST_GWM_TOTAL_TBL}
SELECT CASE 
WHEN tb1.vin IS NOT NULL THEN tb1.vin 
WHEN tb2.vin IS NOT NULL THEN tb2.vin 
ELSE NULL END AS vin,
CASE 
WHEN tb1.ts IS NOT NULL THEN tb1.ts 
WHEN tb2.ts IS NOT NULL THEN tb2.ts 
ELSE NULL END AS ts,
CASE 
WHEN tb1.oem IS NOT NULL THEN tb1.oem 
WHEN tb2.oem IS NOT NULL THEN tb2.oem 
ELSE NULL END AS oem, 
CASE 
WHEN tb1.cartype IS NOT NULL THEN tb1.cartype 
WHEN tb2.cartype IS NOT NULL THEN tb2.cartype 
ELSE NULL END AS cartype,  
CASE 
WHEN tb1.brand IS NOT NULL THEN tb1.brand 
WHEN tb2.brand IS NOT NULL THEN tb2.brand 
ELSE NULL END AS brand,   
CASE 
WHEN tb1.createtime IS NOT NULL THEN tb1.createtime 
WHEN tb2.createtime IS NOT NULL THEN tb2.createtime 
ELSE NULL END AS createtime, 
CASE 
WHEN tb1.rollingcounter IS NOT NULL THEN tb1.rollingcounter 
WHEN tb2.rollingcounter IS NOT NULL THEN tb2.rollingcounter 
ELSE NULL END AS rollingcounter,  
c_abnorflam, 
c_brkeopera, 
tcuquery, 
synchrosiglextc, 
cvoflg, 
cvorelease, 
intkmanifpres, 
intkmanifpresphyslimit, 
airmass, 
tolegrrate, 
engoiltemp, 
inneegrrate, 
accepedalangle, 
ignadvanangle, 
innetoqtargval, 
igntoqtargval, 
relaircharge, 
canispurgvolm, 
throttvlvposi, 
engspd,
engreverseflg, 
engrohsig0, 
engrohsig1, 
engrohsig2, 
engrohsig3, 
uegolam, 
resetapplienvit, 
resetid, 
resetval, 
resetnum, 
resetidlastim, 
altudcorcfactor,
intkvvtposi, 
intkvvttargposi, 
exhautvvtposi, 
exhautvvttargposi, 
oilinjtpulwidth, 
hegooxysensv, 
railpres_ctrl, 
CASE 
WHEN tb1.engtemp IS NOT NULL THEN tb1.engtemp 
WHEN tb2.engtemp IS NOT NULL THEN tb2.engtemp 
ELSE NULL END AS engtemp, 
gpfcarbload,
flgdrvbehavr, 
tolnum_shrpacc, 
avgacc_shrpacc, 
avgv_shrpacc, 
avgengspd_shrpacc, 
avgairchrg_shrpacc, 
time_shrpacc, 
tolnum_shrpdec, 
avgdec_shrpdec, 
avgv_shrpdec, 
avgengspd_shrpdec, 
avgairchrg_shrpdec, 
time_shrpdec, 
tolnum_shrptrn, 
avgtrn_shrptrn, 
avgv_shrptrn, 
time_shrptrn, 
drvmode, 
engineworkconareanum1, 
oilcorrectfactornum, 
oilcorrectfactorreliability, 
flg_shrpacc, 
flg_shrpdec, 
flg_shrptrn, 
flg_drvhabt, 
CASE 
WHEN tb1.engmodeltemp IS NOT NULL THEN tb1.engmodeltemp 
WHEN tb2.engmodeltemp IS NOT NULL THEN tb2.engmodeltemp 
ELSE NULL END AS engmodeltemp, 
CASE 
WHEN tb1.engmodelreftemp IS NOT NULL THEN tb1.engmodelreftemp 
WHEN tb2.engmodelreftemp IS NOT NULL THEN tb2.engmodelreftemp 
ELSE NULL END AS engmodelreftemp,  
normaldrivingpetrolwear, 
intensedrivingpetrolwear, 
airconditionerpetrolwear, 
idlepetrolwear, 
cycletotaloilwear, 
pasttotaloilwear10sec, 
remainingoillevel, 
dtcmalfunctioninfo, 
ccf, 
CASE 
WHEN tb1.regedemandmax IS NOT NULL THEN tb1.regedemandmax 
WHEN tb2.regedemandmax IS NOT NULL THEN tb2.regedemandmax 
ELSE NULL END AS regedemandmax,  
engineworkconareanum2, 
oiltemp_coolwatertemp_areanum, 
CASE 
WHEN tb1.regedemandmaxid IS NOT NULL THEN tb1.regedemandmaxid 
WHEN tb2.regedemandmaxid IS NOT NULL THEN tb2.regedemandmaxid 
ELSE NULL END AS regedemandmaxid, 
gpfstate, 
CASE 
WHEN tb1.ambienttemp IS NOT NULL THEN tb1.ambienttemp 
WHEN tb2.ambienttemp IS NOT NULL THEN tb2.ambienttemp 
ELSE NULL END AS ambienttemp,  
CASE 
WHEN tb1.ashinflu IS NOT NULL THEN tb1.ashinflu 
WHEN tb2.ashinflu IS NOT NULL THEN tb2.ashinflu 
ELSE NULL END AS ashinflu, 
gpftemp, 
oxymass, 
gpfcarbloadmeas, 
CASE 
WHEN tb1.gpfcarbloadmodel IS NOT NULL THEN tb1.gpfcarbloadmodel 
WHEN tb2.gpfcarbloadmodel IS NOT NULL THEN tb2.gpfcarbloadmodel 
ELSE NULL END AS gpfcarbloadmodel, 
CASE 
WHEN tb1.drivingmileage IS NOT NULL THEN tb1.drivingmileage 
WHEN tb2.drivingmileage IS NOT NULL THEN tb2.drivingmileage 
ELSE NULL END AS drivingmileage, 
dsmready1, 
lamcontlfactor1, 
timnormstate, 
lamcontlfactor2, 
distacmilactvat, 
locatoxysens, 
distacdiagcodclear, 
obdrequrt, 
dsmready2, 
numwamup, 
coolwatertempdst_snsr, 
engspd_raw, 
intkairtemp_snsr, 
airmass_snsr, 
absotdveposi1, 
evapvaporpres, 
oxygsenslsu, 
oxygsensorv, 
vesysv, 
accepedalposid, 
relfuellvl, 
accepedalposie, 
secoxysensfueltrim, 
reldveposi, 
coolwatertempdst, 
coolwatertempust,
lamcontlfactor3, 
logtrmfueltrim, 
absotdveposi2, 
manifpres, 
railpres_raw, 
desirddveposi, 
commddtycyclfuelprgcontl, 
ambientpres, 
coolwatertempust2, 
airfuelratio, 
catalsttemp, 
relairmass, 
relaircharge_absladval, 
airfuelcommdratio, 
ingangle_cyl1, 
shrtrmfueltrim, 
carspd,
posstatus, 
lat, 
lon, 
londir, 
speedkn, 
tracktrue, 
magvar, 
modeind, 
tirprsfl, 
tirtempfl, 
tirprsfr, 
tirtempfr, 
tirprsrl, 
tirtemprl, 
tirprsrr, 
tirtemprr, 
iuprnumavltr, 
iuprnumasnsrmnt, 
caucoderltim, 
caucodetwc, 
iuprnumadiagtwc, 
iuprdenodiagtwc, 
iuprnumadyndiaglsu, 
iuprnumapladiaglsu, 
caucodedyndiaglsu, 
iuprnumarltim, 
iuprnumavltl, 
caucodepladiaglsu, 
iuprnumadtesk1, 
iuprdenodtesk1, 
caucodevltl, 
iuprnumarohdtesk, 
iuprdenorohdtesk, 
caucodevltr, 
caucodesnsrmnt, 
caucodedtesk1, 
caucoderohdtesk, 
genldeno, 
battvolt, 
tolengstrtnum, 
tolengstrtsuccnum, 
drivingmileagecycl, 
tolruntim, 
runtimidl, 
dvefd, 
runtimaccelow, 
runtimaccehigh, 
faltlvlthrottzeroslv, 
runtimdecehigh, 
runtimdecelow, 
airmasslv, 
fairmasslv, 
faltlvlthrottairmasslv, 
throttvsens1zeroslv, 
throttvsens1fzeroslv, 
throttvsens2zeroslv, 
throttvsens2fzeroslv, 
faltlvlmaxhdr, 
summassflw, 
sumpistnblow, 
faltlvlminhdr, 
sumoilcomsumtcrkcs, 
falllvldskv, 
frmnumlamclose, 
faltlvlad, 
railpres_fild, 
railpres_rel, 
faltlvlinptlogic, 
faltlvlsyn, 
faltnumpedalposd, 
faltnumpedalpose, 
oxysensfd, 
faltlvlclmpswth, 
faltlvlidlspdmin, 
faltlvlidlspdmax, 
faltlvlidlspdnpl, 
t_engstrt, 
t_engstal, 
c_suprknk, 
c_hspsecinjectiondyn, 
c_preigndetct, 
engspdgradt1cycl, 
filtgradtmanifpres, 
preignratio, 
knkratio, 
ignangle, 
relaircharge_cyl, 
\"1stpreignnum\", 
\"2ndpreignnum\", 
\"3rdpreignnum\", 
\"4thpreignnum\", 
intkairtemp, 
reloilpres, 
thermostatdiagflg, 
thermostatdiagena, 
drivingcyclnum_hot, 
airmass1, 
engmodelreftemp_end, 
drivingcyclnum_cold, 
stkchecksen1high, 
stkchecksen1low, 
stkchecksen2high, 
stkchecksen2low, 
toltempsensmeanval, 
tfa1coldstrt, 
tfa2coldstrt, 
cendiagstat, 
intkairtempsensval1, 
intkairtempsensval2, 
airmassfilt, 
engstptim,
CASE 
WHEN tb1.year IS NOT NULL THEN tb1.year 
WHEN tb2.year IS NOT NULL THEN tb2.year 
ELSE NULL END AS year,  
CASE 
WHEN tb1.month IS NOT NULL THEN tb1.month 
WHEN tb2.month IS NOT NULL THEN tb2.month 
ELSE NULL END AS month, 
CASE 
WHEN tb1.day IS NOT NULL THEN tb1.day 
WHEN tb2.day IS NOT NULL THEN tb2.day 
ELSE NULL END AS day 
FROM  
(SELECT * FROM ${PST_HIVE_SRC_DB}.${PST_HIVE_SRC_ECU_DATA} WHERE createtime < to_iso8601(current_date)) AS tb1
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM ${PST_HIVE_DEST_DB}.${PST_GWM_TOTAL_TBL_TEMP} WHERE createtime < to_iso8601(current_date)) AS tb2 ON (tb1.vin = tb2.vin AND tb1.ts = tb2.ts) 
;
"
```

The ecu_data table DDL:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `test_gwm_ecu_data`(
`vin` string COMMENT '?????',
`ts` string COMMENT '???,???yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS',
`oem` string COMMENT '???',
`cartype` string COMMENT '??',
`brand` string COMMENT '??',
`rollingcounter` string COMMENT '???',
`createtime` string COMMENT '????',
`engineworkconareanum1` string COMMENT '?????????1',
`oilcorrectfactornum` string COMMENT '??????????',
`oilcorrectfactorreliability` string COMMENT '?????????',
`engtemp` string COMMENT '????',
`flg_shrpacc` string COMMENT '?????????',
`flg_shrpdec` string COMMENT '?????????',
`flg_shrptrn` string COMMENT '?????????',
`flg_drvhabt` string COMMENT '??????????',
`engmodeltemp` string COMMENT '???????????????',
`engmodelreftemp` string COMMENT '????????????????????',
`normaldrivingpetrolwear` string COMMENT '?????????',
`intensedrivingpetrolwear` string COMMENT '?????????',
`airconditionerpetrolwear` string COMMENT '???????',
`idlepetrolwear` string COMMENT '???????',
`cycletotaloilwear` string COMMENT '???????',
`pasttotaloilwear10sec` string COMMENT '10????',
`remainingoillevel` string COMMENT '????',
`dtcmalfunctioninfo` string COMMENT 'DTC?????',
`ccf` string COMMENT 'CCF?',
`regedemandmax` string COMMENT '????',
`engineworkconareanum2` string COMMENT '?????????2',
`oiltemp_coolwatertemp_areanum` string COMMENT '????-??????',
`regedemandmaxid` string COMMENT '????',
`gpfstate` string COMMENT 'GPF????',
`ambienttemp` string COMMENT '????',
`ashinflu` string COMMENT '????',
`gpftemp` string COMMENT 'GPF?????',
`oxymass` string COMMENT '???',
`gpfcarbloadmeas` string COMMENT 'GPF??????',
`gpfcarbloadmodel` string COMMENT 'GPF??????',
`drivingmileage` string COMMENT '????????')
COMMENT ' GWM ecu?????'
PARTITIONED BY (
`year` int,
`month` int,
`day` int)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION
'ks3://knocking-test/perf-test/test_gwm_ecu_data';
```

the temp table DDL

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "
INSERT INTO ${PST_HIVE_DEST_DB}.${PST_GWM_TOTAL_TBL_TEMP}
SELECT CASE 
WHEN tb1.vin IS NOT NULL THEN tb1.vin 
WHEN tb2.vin IS NOT NULL THEN tb2.vin 
WHEN tb3.vin IS NOT NULL THEN tb3.vin 
WHEN tb4.vin IS NOT NULL THEN tb4.vin 
WHEN tb5.vin IS NOT NULL THEN tb5.vin 
WHEN tb6.vin IS NOT NULL THEN tb6.vin 
WHEN tb7.vin IS NOT NULL THEN tb7.vin 
WHEN tb8.vin IS NOT NULL THEN tb8.vin 
ELSE NULL END AS vin,
CASE 
WHEN tb1.ts IS NOT NULL THEN tb1.ts 
WHEN tb2.ts IS NOT NULL THEN tb2.ts 
WHEN tb3.ts IS NOT NULL THEN tb3.ts 
WHEN tb4.ts IS NOT NULL THEN tb4.ts 
WHEN tb5.ts IS NOT NULL THEN tb5.ts 
WHEN tb6.ts IS NOT NULL THEN tb6.ts 
WHEN tb7.ts IS NOT NULL THEN tb7.ts 
WHEN tb8.ts IS NOT NULL THEN tb8.ts 
ELSE NULL END AS ts,
CASE 
WHEN tb1.oem IS NOT NULL THEN tb1.oem 
WHEN tb2.oem IS NOT NULL THEN tb2.oem 
WHEN tb3.oem IS NOT NULL THEN tb3.oem 
WHEN tb4.oem IS NOT NULL THEN tb4.oem 
WHEN tb5.oem IS NOT NULL THEN tb5.oem 
WHEN tb6.oem IS NOT NULL THEN tb6.oem 
WHEN tb7.oem IS NOT NULL THEN tb7.oem 
WHEN tb8.oem IS NOT NULL THEN tb8.oem 
ELSE NULL END AS oem, 
CASE 
WHEN tb1.cartype IS NOT NULL THEN tb1.cartype 
WHEN tb2.cartype IS NOT NULL THEN tb2.cartype 
WHEN tb3.cartype IS NOT NULL THEN tb3.cartype 
WHEN tb4.cartype IS NOT NULL THEN tb4.cartype 
WHEN tb5.cartype IS NOT NULL THEN tb5.cartype 
WHEN tb6.cartype IS NOT NULL THEN tb6.cartype 
WHEN tb7.cartype IS NOT NULL THEN tb7.cartype 
WHEN tb8.cartype IS NOT NULL THEN tb8.cartype 
ELSE NULL END AS cartype,  
CASE 
WHEN tb1.brand IS NOT NULL THEN tb1.brand 
WHEN tb2.brand IS NOT NULL THEN tb2.brand 
WHEN tb3.brand IS NOT NULL THEN tb3.brand 
WHEN tb4.brand IS NOT NULL THEN tb4.brand 
WHEN tb5.brand IS NOT NULL THEN tb5.brand 
WHEN tb6.brand IS NOT NULL THEN tb6.brand 
WHEN tb7.brand IS NOT NULL THEN tb7.brand 
WHEN tb8.brand IS NOT NULL THEN tb8.brand 
ELSE NULL END AS brand,   
CASE 
WHEN tb1.createtime IS NOT NULL THEN tb1.createtime 
WHEN tb2.createtime IS NOT NULL THEN tb2.createtime 
WHEN tb3.createtime IS NOT NULL THEN tb3.createtime 
WHEN tb4.createtime IS NOT NULL THEN tb4.createtime 
WHEN tb5.createtime IS NOT NULL THEN tb5.createtime 
WHEN tb6.createtime IS NOT NULL THEN tb6.createtime 
WHEN tb7.createtime IS NOT NULL THEN tb7.createtime 
WHEN tb8.createtime IS NOT NULL THEN tb8.createtime 
ELSE NULL END AS createtime, 
CASE 
WHEN tb2.rollingcounter IS NOT NULL THEN tb2.rollingcounter 
WHEN tb3.rollingcounter IS NOT NULL THEN tb3.rollingcounter 
WHEN tb4.rollingcounter IS NOT NULL THEN tb4.rollingcounter 
WHEN tb5.rollingcounter IS NOT NULL THEN tb5.rollingcounter 
WHEN tb6.rollingcounter IS NOT NULL THEN tb6.rollingcounter 
WHEN tb7.rollingcounter IS NOT NULL THEN tb7.rollingcounter 
WHEN tb8.rollingcounter IS NOT NULL THEN tb8.rollingcounter 
ELSE NULL END AS rollingcounter,  
c_abnorflam, 
c_brkeopera, 
tcuquery, 
synchrosiglextc, 
cvoflg, 
cvorelease, 
intkmanifpres, 
intkmanifpresphyslimit, 
airmass, 
tolegrrate, 
engoiltemp, 
inneegrrate, 
accepedalangle, 
ignadvanangle, 
innetoqtargval, 
igntoqtargval, 
relaircharge, 
canispurgvolm, 
throttvlvposi, 
CASE 
WHEN tb3.engspd IS NOT NULL THEN tb3.engspd 
WHEN tb7.engspd IS NOT NULL THEN tb7.engspd 
ELSE NULL END AS engspd, 
engreverseflg, 
engrohsig0, 
engrohsig1, 
engrohsig2, 
engrohsig3, 
uegolam, 
resetapplienvit, 
resetid, 
resetval, 
resetnum, 
resetidlastim, 
CASE 
WHEN tb3.altudcorcfactor IS NOT NULL THEN tb3.altudcorcfactor 
WHEN tb6.altudcorcfactor IS NOT NULL THEN tb6.altudcorcfactor 
WHEN tb7.altudcorcfactor IS NOT NULL THEN tb7.altudcorcfactor 
ELSE NULL END AS altudcorcfactor, 
intkvvtposi, 
intkvvttargposi, 
exhautvvtposi, 
exhautvvttargposi, 
oilinjtpulwidth, 
hegooxysensv, 
railpres_ctrl, 
CASE 
WHEN tb3.engtemp IS NOT NULL THEN tb3.engtemp 
WHEN tb7.engtemp IS NOT NULL THEN tb7.engtemp 
WHEN tb8.engtemp IS NOT NULL THEN tb8.engtemp 
ELSE NULL END AS engtemp, 
CASE 
WHEN tb3.gpfcarbload IS NOT NULL THEN tb3.gpfcarbload 
WHEN tb6.gpfcarbload IS NOT NULL THEN tb6.gpfcarbload 
ELSE NULL END AS gpfcarbload,  
flgdrvbehavr, 
tolnum_shrpacc, 
avgacc_shrpacc, 
avgv_shrpacc, 
avgengspd_shrpacc, 
avgairchrg_shrpacc, 
time_shrpacc, 
tolnum_shrpdec, 
avgdec_shrpdec, 
avgv_shrpdec, 
avgengspd_shrpdec, 
avgairchrg_shrpdec, 
time_shrpdec, 
tolnum_shrptrn, 
avgtrn_shrptrn, 
avgv_shrptrn, 
time_shrptrn, 
drvmode, 
CASE 
WHEN tb8.engmodeltemp IS NOT NULL THEN tb8.engmodeltemp 
ELSE NULL END AS engmodeltemp, 
CASE 
WHEN tb8.engmodelreftemp IS NOT NULL THEN tb8.engmodelreftemp 
ELSE NULL END AS engmodelreftemp,  
CASE 
WHEN tb6.regedemandmax IS NOT NULL THEN tb6.regedemandmax 
ELSE NULL END AS regedemandmax,  
CASE 
WHEN tb6.regedemandmaxid IS NOT NULL THEN tb6.regedemandmaxid 
ELSE NULL END AS regedemandmaxid, 
CASE 
WHEN tb4.ambienttemp IS NOT NULL THEN tb4.ambienttemp 
WHEN tb6.ambienttemp IS NOT NULL THEN tb6.ambienttemp 
WHEN tb7.ambienttemp IS NOT NULL THEN tb7.ambienttemp 
WHEN tb8.ambienttemp IS NOT NULL THEN tb8.ambienttemp 
ELSE NULL END AS ambienttemp,  
CASE 
WHEN tb6.ashinflu IS NOT NULL THEN tb6.ashinflu 
ELSE NULL END AS ashinflu, 
CASE 
WHEN tb6.gpfcarbloadmodel IS NOT NULL THEN tb6.gpfcarbloadmodel 
ELSE NULL END AS gpfcarbloadmodel, 
CASE 
WHEN tb4.drivingmileage IS NOT NULL THEN tb4.drivingmileage 
WHEN tb6.drivingmileage IS NOT NULL THEN tb6.drivingmileage 
WHEN tb7.drivingmileage IS NOT NULL THEN tb7.drivingmileage 
ELSE NULL END AS drivingmileage, 
dsmready1, 
lamcontlfactor1, 
timnormstate, 
lamcontlfactor2, 
distacmilactvat, 
locatoxysens, 
distacdiagcodclear, 
obdrequrt, 
dsmready2, 
numwamup, 
coolwatertempdst_snsr, 
engspd_raw, 
intkairtemp_snsr, 
airmass_snsr, 
absotdveposi1, 
evapvaporpres, 
oxygsenslsu, 
oxygsensorv, 
vesysv, 
accepedalposid, 
relfuellvl, 
accepedalposie, 
secoxysensfueltrim, 
reldveposi, 
coolwatertempdst, 
CASE 
WHEN tb4.coolwatertempust IS NOT NULL THEN tb4.coolwatertempust 
WHEN tb8.coolwatertempust IS NOT NULL THEN tb8.coolwatertempust 
ELSE NULL END AS coolwatertempust,
lamcontlfactor3, 
logtrmfueltrim, 
absotdveposi2, 
manifpres, 
railpres_raw, 
desirddveposi, 
commddtycyclfuelprgcontl, 
ambientpres, 
coolwatertempust2, 
airfuelratio, 
catalsttemp, 
relairmass, 
relaircharge_absladval, 
airfuelcommdratio, 
ingangle_cyl1, 
shrtrmfueltrim, 
CASE 
WHEN tb4.carspd IS NOT NULL THEN tb4.carspd 
WHEN tb7.carspd IS NOT NULL THEN tb7.carspd 
WHEN tb8.carspd IS NOT NULL THEN tb8.carspd 
ELSE NULL END AS carspd, 
posstatus, 
lat, 
lon, 
londir, 
speedkn, 
tracktrue, 
magvar, 
modeind, 
tirprsfl, 
tirtempfl, 
tirprsfr, 
tirtempfr, 
tirprsrl, 
tirtemprl, 
tirprsrr, 
tirtemprr, 
iuprnumavltr, 
iuprnumasnsrmnt, 
caucoderltim, 
caucodetwc, 
iuprnumadiagtwc, 
iuprdenodiagtwc, 
iuprnumadyndiaglsu, 
iuprnumapladiaglsu, 
caucodedyndiaglsu, 
iuprnumarltim, 
iuprnumavltl, 
caucodepladiaglsu, 
iuprnumadtesk1, 
iuprdenodtesk1, 
caucodevltl, 
iuprnumarohdtesk, 
iuprdenorohdtesk, 
caucodevltr, 
caucodesnsrmnt, 
caucodedtesk1, 
caucoderohdtesk, 
genldeno, 
battvolt, 
tolengstrtnum, 
tolengstrtsuccnum, 
drivingmileagecycl, 
tolruntim, 
runtimidl, 
dvefd, 
runtimaccelow, 
runtimaccehigh, 
faltlvlthrottzeroslv, 
runtimdecehigh, 
runtimdecelow, 
airmasslv, 
fairmasslv, 
faltlvlthrottairmasslv, 
throttvsens1zeroslv, 
throttvsens1fzeroslv, 
throttvsens2zeroslv, 
throttvsens2fzeroslv, 
faltlvlmaxhdr, 
summassflw, 
sumpistnblow, 
faltlvlminhdr, 
sumoilcomsumtcrkcs, 
falllvldskv, 
frmnumlamclose, 
faltlvlad, 
railpres_fild, 
railpres_rel, 
faltlvlinptlogic, 
faltlvlsyn, 
faltnumpedalposd, 
faltnumpedalpose, 
oxysensfd, 
faltlvlclmpswth, 
faltlvlidlspdmin, 
faltlvlidlspdmax, 
faltlvlidlspdnpl, 
t_engstrt, 
t_engstal, 
c_suprknk, 
c_hspsecinjectiondyn, 
c_preigndetct, 
engspdgradt1cycl, 
filtgradtmanifpres, 
preignratio, 
knkratio, 
ignangle, 
relaircharge_cyl, 
\"1stpreignnum\", 
\"2ndpreignnum\", 
\"3rdpreignnum\", 
\"4thpreignnum\", 
intkairtemp, 
reloilpres, 
thermostatdiagflg, 
thermostatdiagena, 
drivingcyclnum_hot, 
airmass1, 
engmodelreftemp_end, 
drivingcyclnum_cold, 
stkchecksen1high, 
stkchecksen1low, 
stkchecksen2high, 
stkchecksen2low, 
toltempsensmeanval, 
tfa1coldstrt, 
tfa2coldstrt, 
cendiagstat, 
intkairtempsensval1, 
intkairtempsensval2, 
airmassfilt, 
engstptim,
CASE 
WHEN tb1.year IS NOT NULL THEN tb1.year 
WHEN tb2.year IS NOT NULL THEN tb2.year 
WHEN tb3.year IS NOT NULL THEN tb3.year 
WHEN tb4.year IS NOT NULL THEN tb4.year 
WHEN tb5.year IS NOT NULL THEN tb5.year 
WHEN tb6.year IS NOT NULL THEN tb6.year 
WHEN tb7.year IS NOT NULL THEN tb7.year 
WHEN tb8.year IS NOT NULL THEN tb8.year 
ELSE NULL END AS year,  
CASE 
WHEN tb1.month IS NOT NULL THEN tb1.month 
WHEN tb2.month IS NOT NULL THEN tb2.month 
WHEN tb3.month IS NOT NULL THEN tb3.month 
WHEN tb4.month IS NOT NULL THEN tb4.month 
WHEN tb5.month IS NOT NULL THEN tb5.month 
WHEN tb6.month IS NOT NULL THEN tb6.month 
WHEN tb7.month IS NOT NULL THEN tb7.month 
WHEN tb8.month IS NOT NULL THEN tb8.month 
ELSE NULL END AS month, 
CASE 
WHEN tb1.day IS NOT NULL THEN tb1.day 
WHEN tb2.day IS NOT NULL THEN tb2.day 
WHEN tb3.day IS NOT NULL THEN tb3.day 
WHEN tb4.day IS NOT NULL THEN tb4.day 
WHEN tb5.day IS NOT NULL THEN tb5.day 
WHEN tb6.day IS NOT NULL THEN tb6.day 
WHEN tb7.day IS NOT NULL THEN tb7.day 
WHEN tb8.day IS NOT NULL THEN tb8.day 
ELSE NULL END AS day 
FROM  
(SELECT * FROM ${PST_HIVE_SRC_DB}.${PST_HIVE_SRC_GPS} WHERE createtime < to_iso8601(current_date)) AS tb1
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM ${PST_HIVE_SRC_DB}.${PST_HIVE_SRC_DRVHABT} WHERE createtime < to_iso8601(current_date)) AS tb2 ON (tb1.vin = tb2.vin AND tb1.ts = tb2.ts) 
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM ${PST_HIVE_SRC_DB}.${PST_HIVE_SRC_ABNORMALFLAMEOUT} WHERE createtime < to_iso8601(current_date)) AS tb3 ON (tb1.vin = tb3.vin AND tb1.ts = tb3.ts) 
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM ${PST_HIVE_SRC_DB}.${PST_HIVE_SRC_FAULTOUTPUT} WHERE createtime < to_iso8601(current_date)) AS tb4 ON (tb1.vin = tb4.vin AND tb1.ts = tb4.ts) 
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM ${PST_HIVE_SRC_DB}.${PST_HIVE_SRC_PERIOD30S} WHERE createtime < to_iso8601(current_date)) AS tb5 ON (tb1.vin = tb5.vin AND tb1.ts = tb5.ts) 
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM ${PST_HIVE_SRC_DB}.${PST_HIVE_SRC_POWERON} WHERE createtime < to_iso8601(current_date)) AS tb6 ON (tb1.vin = tb6.vin AND tb1.ts = tb6.ts)
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM ${PST_HIVE_SRC_DB}.${PST_HIVE_SRC_SUPERKNOCK} WHERE createtime < to_iso8601(current_date)) AS tb7 ON (tb1.vin = tb7.vin AND tb1.ts = tb7.ts) 
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM ${PST_HIVE_SRC_DB}.${PST_HIVE_SRC_WTDIAGNOSISMODEL} WHERE createtime < to_iso8601(current_date)) AS tb8 ON (tb1.vin = tb8.vin AND tb1.ts = tb8.ts)
;
"
```

Comment: What version of Presto are you running? Do your table have stats? If so, make sure to turn on the cost based optimizations (unless on a recent version of Presto that has them enabled by default): https://prestosql.io/docs/current/optimizer/cost-based-optimizations.html

Comment: Presto version: 0.215

Comment: we leave the CBO and join distribution strategy as default. I can see from SQL explain that the distribution strategy is 'Distribution: PARTITIONED'

Comment: That version is more than one year old. I suggest you try with a more recent version (the latest one is 330, which you can download here:https://prestosql.io/download.html. Version 330 has the cost based optimizations turned on by default, which should help with this query assuming you have stats for your tables (which you can compute using ANALYZE if not). Also, for troubleshooting questions, it's easier to discuss them on the Presto Slack: https://prestosql.io/slack.html

Comment: the current version that I can see from https://prestodb.io/ is 0.231.1. Cannot find 330  version.

Comment: Check the link I posted above: https://prestosql.io/download.html